# Compare and match numbers from a word/excel file in C C++

Tags: c++, c, text, hashmap

I have to compare two columns in a word file which are filled with numbers row wise. For instance if there is a word file which has these two columns:

```
1     56
2     57
3     59
4     63
```

Then if I am giving the input 2 the output should be 57 in C C++. What logic will help in mapping a table and using its values?
Please help. So far I could not think of any approach. I am reading the file line by line using this piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char const* const fileName = argv[1]; /* should check that argc > 1 */
    FILE* file = fopen("C:\\Users\\parth\\Downloads\\state_model_files.txt", "r"); /* should check the result */
    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        /* note that fgets don't strip the terminating \n, checking its
        presence would allow to handle lines longer that sizeof(line) */
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    /* may check feof here to make a difference between eof and io failure -- network
    timeout for instance */





    fclose(file);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you know that the values in the first column will be unique, then yes, a hashmap would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @chrisD how can I implement it? Could you help?

Comment: The first problem is that you need to find a library to actually *read* the Word or Excel file. At least if it's not a simple [comma-separated values (or CSV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, after reading how do I treat them as columns or rows. Another solution is that I make the data in an excel file.

Comment: ***If*** the left hand column will always have contiguous numbers, you can put the other column(s) into a row at that index in a `std::vector`, which will be faster than using a hash table.  Anyway, you need to pick a language and go through some introductory material until you have some idea how to write the code yourself... this web site is neither a tutoring nor code writing service, but you can ask for help when you get stuck with *specific* technical issues.

Comment: @TonyD I have edited. :) Can you help now?

Comment: @tarabhargava ChrisD posted a reasonable solution - not sure why he/she deleted it.  Did you get a copy before it was deleted?

Comment: No I couldn't take a copy before he removed @TonyD.

Comment: @ChrisD: your answer was more or less what Tara seems to need - any particular reason for deleting it?  Tara - in general, you should push yourself a bit further before asking for help.  The individual steps of getting numbers from a line of input, storing them in a data structure, looking them up afterwards are all easily researched individually on S.O..

Comment: both excel and word files have massive amounts of formating/layout data in them what is displayed on the screen when the excel or MS-Word application is run.  So, just fgets(), sscan() into a char * arrayOfWords[] is just the start (and probably not anything like the final code) .

Comment: I would suggest forgetting about using a hashmap as given a number like 3, can immediately access array[3] to get the value.

Comment: Please pick a language,  The answer will be dramatically different depending on which language is actually used to implement the function

Comment: @TonyD Undeleted. Wasn't sure if I should post a complete code sample. Tara, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want to do is (1) open the file, (2) grab a line from the file, (3) write the values of each column to some variable, and (4) store them into a map. Later on, you can make queries like the one you suggested in your post. Note, the approach below makes certain assumptions about your input data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ifstream in(argv[1]);
    if(!in) { 
        cout << "Could not open file " << argv[1] << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    map<int, int> m;

    int c1, c2;

    string fields;
    while(getline(in, fields)) {
        istringstream ss(fields);
        ss >> c1 >> c2;
        m[c1] = c2;
    }
    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a nice start.  My derived code fleshes out a few more details & error checking, and remains available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c19cde362591f4a9) for whatever it's worth.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD D thanks a ton for the help. I am pretty new to C++. I wonder if you could tell me as to how I can match the two columns. Like with an input of I get output as 59.
I am sorry for my bad coding skills.

Comment: As I mentioned above, @ChrisD I am indeed grateful for your help but could you help me with the matching problem. Really appreciate your help.